# How do I know if the integrity of the asset table is good up or not?

Tags: mysql

1) I have migrated a lot of articles from Joomla 1.5 to joomla 3. Migration went on mostly fine. However, there are a couple of articles which do not get saved when I press the save button in article editor. It does say error while saving article but doesn't mention what error.

2) I looked into the asset table after someone mentioned that the integrity of my asset table may not be correct. I was confused when I saw the different columns. Hence my 2nd question is what is Nested set Parent, Nested set lft and nested set right in the asset table.
do lft and right need to have unique values?

Comment: Did you already see these two links?
http://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets
http://docs.joomla.org/Fixing_the_assets_table

Comment: need to take a look at both links properly and try figuring out what I did wrong. will be back with some analysis.. Thanks :)

Comment: Also nested sets are explained here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/unexpected-parent-tag-association/2320#2320

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have cleared out all elements marked trash(if any), you may have conflicting alias.

Try the 'Rebuild Menu items' in Joomla Menu Manager (I know not articles but can clear up assets table issues sometimes).

And then as @cppl mentions ACL manager is excellent tool for fixing remaining assets table issues without having to touch the database.  I find that after installing ACL Manager that I am always having to fix minor Assets Table issues.

ACL Manager is a 'paid for' extension, I have no affiliation and I would suggest it is worth the purchase E14.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the mentioned documents, have you looked at [ACL Manager](http://www.aclmanager.net) which has built in repair tools which we find essential for sites post migration.