# Unexpected parent tag association

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, tags

I'm using 3.3.0 and started playing with the tags.  I've noticed that all of the tags recently created have the Joomla tag as their parent.  When I edit the tag, the Parent pull down menu is set to None; however if I Unpublish the Joomla tag, then the subsequent tags get unpublished as well (and cannot be published until I publish the Joomla tag).  Is this expected behavior?

---

**Some screen shots**

Components => Tags

I've unpublished the tag Joomla which also unpublishes most of my other tags (oddly, not the Baking, although that one was added at a different time than the others, leading me to believe that something has changed in the meantime).  If I click on the status of SciLab, it will not change.  If I toggle the status of Joomla, all (save for Baking) follow suit.

[image]

Components => Tags => SciLab

No parent is set.  Here I can publish the tag, and it seems to persist until I toggle the Joomla tag; Joomla is still behaving like the parent.

[image]

Components => Tags => Baking

Why baking isn't sharing the fate of all my other tags is beyond me.

[image]

---

**In response to answer by @FFrewin**

Here is a screenshot of my jos_tags table.  It looks as if there are problems with the lft/rgt values.  Additionally, the Path shows that Joomla is the parent of *all* the tags, even though Baking is not behaving as if it has a parent.

[image]

Comment: Did you load any example data when you installed Joomla?

Comment: @BodgeIT Not intentionally.  Joomla was the only tag entry after install.

Comment: Then No it is not expected behaviour.  What's expected is to see Root as the "root" tag.

Comment: Furthermore, in the Tags manager, what do you see? Are your tags children of the Joomla tag ?

Comment: @FFrewin I added screenshots to hopefully show my configuration.  Let me know if you think I should add more information to help with the debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are not any other hacks over the core code that affect the save functions of the component, then this issue makes me think that something can be messed up in the **Nested Set Model** in the **jos_tags table**.

You will need to check your tags db_table with a tool like **phpmyAdmin**, to see about those values, and maybe if you need further advise, post here a screenshot of tags table columns for further investigation.

> For more info, check this very good article that exlains the **[Nested Set
> Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)** concept. A good read for everyone.

### The Nested Set Model diagram:

[image: The Nested Set Model diagram]

### Your Joomla Tags table

But in a brief, if all your tags are those I see in the screenshot, you should expect to see something similar to the screenshot I post here.

What you should care more from my screenshot is the parent_id (of course), the lft, rgt, level and path values.
[image: right tags table for the question]

Since you want all your tags be children of the root tag (meaning having no other tags as parent), then they should be all set to level=1 and parent_id = 1. For lft and rgt values, then all of your tags should have numbers with no larger difference than 1, between their left/right values, while ROOT should have the lft value set to 0 and the right set to the higher number of this calculation: "(total number of tags * 2) -1".

Generally there is not an easy way to deal with this for the com_tags. If it happens that you just have only a few tags, then you could edit the lft/rgt values by hand (of course after have calculate them). If you have an extended number of tags, then you would probably have to look to write a php script, that will calculate and set those values properly.

Hope this helps and will not be too much confusing.

**To be more specific - follow these steps:**

Set ROOT lft/rgt 0-13, Joomla lft/rgt to 1-2 baking 3-4 and continue like this till your last tag travel which should be 11-12. Also remove from the path the joomla and the slash part. But in any case - first take a backup of your db.

Comment: My jos_tags table does have similar entries.  The problem seems to lie in the lft/rgt values and I'll post a screenshot shortly.

Comment: Based on the screenshot in the updated question, would you recommend that I (a) change the lft/rgt values for my tags to 1/2 .. 11/12 (b) set the lft/rgt values for ROOT to 0/11 [or is ROOT a 'tag' and therefore 0/13?] and (c) modify the Path field?

Comment: As I see it, you should set ROOT lft/rgt 0-13, Joomla lft/rgt to 1-2 baking 3-4 and continue like this till your last tag travel which should be 11-12. Also remove from the path the joomla and the slash part. But in any case - first take a backup of your db.

Comment: I know that in some of the other nested tables in Joomla there is a fix table command. Is there one in the tags list view?

Comment: @FFrewin BTW thanks for posting that article! I've read about nested sets and understood the concept, but the lft and rgt bit was a little fuzzy. That article explained it very well!

Comment: @Mathew, I am not aware of something for the tags component and not sure how this can happen through the Joomla backend.

Comment: @bobthechemist : Have you tried the above? How did it go?

Comment: @FFrewin I will soon - just got bombarded at work.

Comment: The menus are nested sets and they have the fix menus button, so you could look and see how it is done there. That might help.

Comment: @FFrewin your comment worked.  I suggested an edit to your answer so that the information from your comment doesn't get lost.