# What does 'lft' and 'rgt' do in #__menu table?

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, mysql

I was trying to manually add menu item to the database. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198806/duplicate-entry-for-key-idx-client-id-parent-id-alias-language-when-manually-i), when I notice these two fields in the `#__menu` table. It seems to me they are auto increasing by 2. For example, if the latest menu item have {lft:121,rgt:122}, then a new menu item will have {lft:123,rgt,124}. A brief searching shows they are related to something called "nested model", and I look at other Joomla tables, many have these two fields too.

Not understanding what they are, I just add new record to the table, and I gave each new record these two fields, keeping the auto increment.

Today I tried to add a new menu item through back-end and get this error message:

> Save failed with the following error: exception
>   'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'MenusTableMenu::_getNode(1, )
>   failed.' in /home/p/public_html/libraries/joomla/table/nested.php:1532
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/joomla/table/nested.php(773):
>   JTableNested->_getNode(1) #1
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/legacy/table/menu.php(243):
>   JTableNested->store(false) #2
>   /home/p/public_html/administrator/components/com_menus/models/item.php(1258):
>   JTableMenu->store() #3
>   /home/p/public_html/administrator/components/com_menus/controllers/item.php(267):
>   MenusModelItem->save(Array) #4
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(728):
>   MenusControllerItem->save() #5
>   /home/p/public_html/administrator/components/com_menus/menus.php(18):
>   JControllerLegacy->execute('apply') #6
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405):
>   require_once('/home/p/public_...') #7
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380):
>   JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/home/p/public_...') #8
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98):
>   JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_menus') #9
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(152):
>   JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch() #10
>   /home/p/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(257):
>   JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute() #11
>   /home/p/public_html/administrator/index.php(51):
>   JApplicationCms->execute() #12 {main}

I see `nested` is involved in this issue, so I guess it has something to do with the two fields that I ignored. How to fix this?

P.S., I hardcoded some PHP to add record into the `#__menu`, I think this also play a part in the problem. Too add menu item, besides `#__menu`, is there any other table I need to take care of?

Comment: To understand about nested set and lft,rgt read here : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/unexpected-parent-tag-association/2320#2320  and  https://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets

Answer (score 4):

The lft and rft code is quite old in Joomla, and only used in a sub-set of core functionality.  Basically it means...

- lft: the item id of the item to the left
- rgt: the item id of the item to the right

If you add items to the table, you'll maybe find you need to "rebuild" the menu.  This is a button at the top of the menu manager that basically sets all the lft and rft values.

If you're adding menu items programmatically, to the database,  you may need to "rebuild" them afterwards.

Further reading

- https://docs.joomla.org/Help35:Menus_Menu_Manager
- https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/how-to-rebuild-menu/
- http://www.itoctopus.com/the-rebuild-button-in-joomlas-menu-manager-page-a-double-edged-sword
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866694/how-to-invoke-menu-rebuild-from-the-custom-front-end-component-in-joomla

Answer (score 0):

Simply - it's for ordering in subsets.
If need real info about it - see Wiki "Nested Sets"

Concerning Joomla and adding menu items via custom PHP - it's simple if you use what provided here https://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets

Concerning of what you should to keep in mind - #__assets table also uses Nested Sets